# Web App from Standalone script to be opened in multiple identical google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Help! I have one standalone script, which I want to be called in 50 separate google spreadsheets onOpen of each of these spreadsheets. I need a web app or something that will run this script as myself, not the user opening one of those 50 sheets, as the script is referring to some other files, to which the users do not have access. **My problem I do know how to make this standalone script run when one of the 50 files is opened - should I put some code (like doGet()) in my spreadsheet bound script orwhere & what???**And should I put something in my standalone script? And can I do this avoiding creating HTML pages etc.? Thanks!

My standalone script that I want to apply to my multiple spreadsheets (in short it gets a name from a cell from the opened spreadsheet, creates a copy of a separate master spreadsheet, put the saved name to the master spsheet, recalculates there, put its back to the open spreadsheet (where the name was initially):

```
var masterFileId = "1i-------------------DM";
var tempHolderFolder = "1D---------------ae";

function ImportIndReport2(personalFileId) {
  var mf = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterFileId);
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(tempHolderFolder);
  var indCopyTest = DriveApp.getFileById(mf.getId()).makeCopy("test temp2", destFolder);
  var URLCopy = indCopyTest.getUrl();
  var currentIdToUse = SpreadsheetApp.openById(personalFileId).getSheetByName('Welcome').getRange('D6').getValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(indCopyTest.getId()).getSheetByName("Welcome").getRange("C6").setValue(currentIdToUse);

  var now = new Date();
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(indCopyTest.getId()).getSheetByName("jj").getRange("A1").setValue(now);

  var oldSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(personalFileId).getSheetByName("jj");
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(personalFileId).deleteSheet(oldSheet);
  var CurrentIdDestination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(personalFileId);
  var indReportToCopy = SpreadsheetApp.openById(indCopyTest.getId()).getSheetByName('jj');
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(indCopyTest.getId()).insertSheet('Temp');
  var tempDestination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(indCopyTest.getId());
  indReportToCopy.getRange("A1:Z30").copyTo(tempDestination.getSheetByName('Temp').getRange("A1:Z30"),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
  indReportToCopy.getRange("A1:Z30").copyTo(tempDestination.getSheetByName('Temp').getRange("A1:Z30"),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT,false);

  tempDestination.getSheetByName('Temp').copyTo(CurrentIdDestination).setName('jj');
  var tempDestinationForDelete = DriveApp.getFileById(indCopyTest.getId());
  tempDestinationForDelete.setTrashed(true);

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<div>The report has been updated</div>").setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setWidth(150).setHeight(100);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Message");
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I have one standalone script, which I want to be called in 50 separate google spreadsheets onOpen of each of these spreadsheets.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, in your showing script, your `ImportIndReport2` works fine. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, importIndreport2 works fine. The problem is this importindreport2 - which is kept in standalone script - does not work, when I call it from another spreadsheet custom menu item. I put it inside of doGet(), and still it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Updated - solved it with clickable url of the webapp script in the individual spreadsheet bound script, and adding simple doGet() with name of my main function (indreport..) to standalone script.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a "web app" it might be better to use an installable on open trigger, but installable triggers are limited to 20 per script / user.

You might create three stand alone projects to hold the triggers and put the main code on a fourth stand alone project to be used as library on the three projects.

Another option is to create and add-on. This might imply extra work but it will be done only once and will be easier to maintain.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first option (3 standalone and one main) - it does not work for other users - as the main code refers to other files, which are accessed by other users. Seems the only option is to publish an add on, which is undesirable as  my users will be confused and scared:(((

Comment: Apparently there something that was not setup correctly. Double check that the user that created the installable triggers has access to the required files and that the main code was adapted properly to work as library. If still want to go with the first option, create a [mcve] and if you still need help, I suggest you to post a new question including the "mcve".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made a typo in my last comment - the users do not have access to these other referred files, so library will not work.